# Check what capabilitie(s) an action requires

Tags: user-roles, capabilities, user-access

I can check whether a user has a given capability or not with `user_can()` function, but how can I check what capability a certain action requires?

For example, I'm using `WP Job Manager` plugin, this plugin introduce a new set of capabilities including `edit_job_listings`. Now a certain user tries to submit the edit job listing form, but he does not have this specific capability.

Now how can I hook into this action (i.e. submiting editing job form) and see what capabilitie(s) this action require in order to be performed successfully. If I can get the answer to this question I can compare it with `user_can()` result and can proceed accordingly with `wp_die()` or something else.

Comment: You can't really. You'd need to look at the source code of the plugin to know for certain.

Comment: Then what would be the best way to proceed in this case? Currently, I'm doing something like this `!current_user_can('edit_job_listings') && !empty($_POST['submit_job']) ? wp_die(...) : 'proceed with request'`. But I thought there would be a better way.

Comment: You need to look at the plugin source or documentation for which capabilities are used. If you're still not sure you should ask the plugin author.